# Heuristic path algorithm (Pohl) completeness

Tags: heuristics

This is a homework question, exactly as follows:

`The heuristic path algorithm (Pohl, 1977) is a best-first search in which the evaluation function is  f(n) = (2-w)g(n) + wh(n)`.

`For what values of w is this complete?`

Here's what I know:

`w = 0: f(n)=2g(n)` --> Uniform Cost Search, which is complete.

`w = 1: f(n)=g(n) + h(n)` --> A*, which is complete.

`w = 2: f(n)=2h(n)` --> greedy Best First Search, which is not complete.

What about all other values of `w`?

Please don't just give the answer, help me get to the solution.

Comment: Interesting thing about "all other values of w" for w>2: They all have the form `f(n) = h(n) - g(n)` with some constants in front of h and g. What impact, if any, does subtracting the cost have on completeness? Seems you should be able to generalize from there.

Comment: @ccoakley if you copy/paste this as an answer, I'll upvote it and accept it.

Comment: It always seems odd making a small homework hint into an answer. I hope it actually helped you.

Comment: @ccoakley it was enough of a hint to help me through it and no one else helped out so I'm more then happy to give you the rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting thing about "all other values of w" for w>2: They all have the form f(n) = h(n) - g(n) with some constants in front of h and g. What impact, if any, does subtracting the cost have on completeness? Seems you should be able to generalize from there.